Unable to get data from mmkv before API calls in react native
I am using zustand and mmkv with tanstack query in my react native app. The issue i am facing is i am setting the access token when the user logs in and i remove the auth stack from navigation and mounts the further stack.
The home screen is mounted first where an API call is made which requires access token, which i am saving to mmkv storage, but when the home page API is made i am unable to get the token, when closing the app and reopening then the token arrives or if i refresh the app. There is some lag in getting from storage i guess.
Heres my code:
Zustand Part:
import {createAuthSlice, IAuthSlice} from '@authScreens/Slice/UserAuthSlice';
import {create} from 'zustand';
import {createJSONStorage, persist} from 'zustand/middleware';
import {zustandStorage} from '@store/MMKVConfig';

interface IStore extends IAuthSlice {}

export const appStore = create<IStore>()(
  persist(
    (set, get, api) => ({
      ...createAuthSlice(set, get, api),
    }),
    {
      name: 'auth-storage',
      storage: createJSONStorage(() => zustandStorage),
    },
  ),
); 

Slice:
export interface IAuthSlice {
  isOnboarded: boolean;
  isLoggedIn: boolean;
  user: Partial<Data>;
  registeredUserdata: IUserRegisterResponse;
  setIsOnboarded: (data: boolean) => void;
  setIsLoggedIn: (data: LoginResponse) => Promise<void>;
  setUserRegistration: (data: UserRegisterResponse) => void;
  setIsLoggedOut: () => void;
}

export const createAuthSlice: StateCreator<IAuthSlice> = set => {
  return {
    isOnboarded: false,
    isLoggedIn: false,
    user: {} as Partial<Data>,
    registeredUserdata: {} as IUserRegisterResponse,
    setIsOnboarded: (data: boolean): void => {
      set({isOnboarded: data});
    },
    setIsLoggedIn: async (data: LoginResponse): Promise<void> => {
      set({user: data?.data, isLoggedIn: true});
    },
    setUserRegistration: (data: UserRegisterResponse): void => {
      set({registeredUserdata: data.data});
    },
    setIsLoggedOut: (): void => {
      set({isLoggedIn: false});
      set({user: {} as Data});
    },
  };
};

Here i am calling the set setIsLoggedIn Method at login screen:
const onSubmit = async (data: ILogin) => {
    const response = (await mutateAsync(data)) as LoginResponse;
    if (response?.status && response?.data?.access_token) {
      setIsLoggedIn(response);
    }
  };

And my token injecting and networking call here:

export function useGetQuery(
  props: Omit<IUseNetworkCallGetBase, 'axiosClient'>,
): UseQueryResult<any, Error> {
  const {
    method,
    queryKey,
    url,
    persist,
    enabled = false,
    params = '',
    select,
  } = props;

  //injecting token here
  axiosClientLMS.interceptors.request.use(async config => {
    if (access_token) {
      config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${access_token}`;
    }
    return config;
  });

  const isReallyEnabled = !!(enabled && access_token);
  const config = {
    axiosClient: axiosClientLMS,
    queryKey: queryKey,
    method: method,
    url: url,
    persist: persist,
    params: params,
    enabled: isReallyEnabled,
    select: select,
  };

  return useRTKQuery(config);
}

